# Prove that the set $C_2(\sigma) = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n| u^Tx=1, x^TAx = 2\sigma\right\}$ is non-empty for some value of $\sigma$.

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

**Problem:** For a given real number $\sigma \ge 0$, consider the set
$$C_2(\sigma) = \left\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n| u'x=1, x^TAx = 2\sigma\right\}.$$
where $A$ is a symmetric, positive definite $n\times n$ matrix, $u = (1,\ldots,1) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $e = (e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n)$.

Prove that the set $C_2(\sigma)$ is non-empty for some value of $\sigma$.

**My attempt:** I have tried to plot the figure in two dimensions to find see some special things (a line and a quadratic function that does not have a common graph), but it is still difficult to see the condition that makes $C_2(\sigma) \neq \varnothing$.

Comment: Some assumptions on $A$ are missing (?) this is not true for $A=0$.

Comment: $x=\frac u {\|u\|^{2}}, \sigma=\frac 1 2 (x^{T}Ax)$

Comment: @daw Sorry for missing assumptions. I have already added all the assumptions of the problem.